# Variable returning null

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm attempting to modify a Google maps API v3 direction script. I thought I had a firm grasp of combining variables etc but then I ran into this problem:

```
function calcRoute() {
    var end = document.getElementById("start").value;
    var street = document.getElementById("street").value;
    var city = document.getElementById("city").value;
    var state = document.getElementById("state").value;
    var zip = document.getElementById("zip").value;
    var start = street + ' ' + city + ' ' + state + ' ' + zip;

    var request = {
        origin:start, 
        destination:end,
        travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
    };
    directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
      }
    });
  }
```

If I create an input with an id of start and change

```
var start =  document.getElementById("start").value;
```

the script works again. however I can't get my combined variable to work:

```
var start = street + ' ' + city + ' ' + state + ' ' + zip;
```

if i make a button to alert(start) it returns null... what am I doing wrong?

Update: Also of note,

if I run:

```
onClick="alert(end)"
```

while

```
<input id="end" name="destination" type="hidden" value="test" />
```

the alert returns "object HTMLInputElement" not "test" as it should.

Comment: Check each individual variable, one is probably NULL

Comment: If you post a link to your page, or alternately use something like JSFiddle and post it there, we can review your whole code in the context of the HTML and DOM and everything.

Comment: If you notice the first line 'var end = document.getElementById("start").value;' it should be 'var end = document.getElementById("end").value;' This fixes the script however I still cant get alert to work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to alert the value of the "end" input you need to do:

```
onClick="alert(document.getElementById('end').value)"
```

As for your start being null problem, I don't believe that one of the variables was null, if I try this:

```
null + " " + null
```

I get "*null null*" (tested both on chrome and firefox).
And so, my question is: where do you try to access the "start" variable from? Is it from inside the function in which it was defined in or outside of it?  You can't access that variable from outside the *calcRoute* function.

So if you are doing something like:

```
<input type="button" onclick="alert(start)" />
```

It's bound to fail, instead do something like this:

```
var start;
function calcRoute() {
    var end = document.getElementById("start").value;
    var street = document.getElementById("street").value;
    var city = document.getElementById("city").value;
    var state = document.getElementById("state").value;
    var zip = document.getElementById("zip").value;
    start = street + ' ' + city + ' ' + state + ' ' + zip;

.....
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation. Haha I was doing exactly what you said would fail. At least now it makes sense as to why it was failing. I just had a small epiphany and a lot more is making sense. Thanks again!